# WMI GetStringValue Returns Null for added registry values

Tags: wmi

I'm going a little crazy here. I am trying to read the value of a registry string value I manually created and every time it returns a null. If I try to read the value of an existing registry string value, it returns the value just fine. Here is the code I'm using:

```
                  ManagementBaseObject rinParams = registry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");

                        rinParams["hDefKey"] = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
                        rinParams["sSubKeyName"] = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework";
                  //      rinParams["sValueName"] = "InstallRoot";
                        rinParams["sValueName"] = "test";


                  ManagementBaseObject routParams = registry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", rinParams, null);

                  if (routParams.Properties["sValue"].Value != null)
                  {
                      routput = routParams.Properties["sValue"].Value.ToString();
                  }
```

What I did was set the code to use the above code to read the value of the "InstallRoot" in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NetFramework\InstallRoot which is a REG_SZ value. I get a successful read and the directory path is returned just fine. I then created another REG_SZ variable name "test" in the same .NetFramework key and commented out the "sValueName" = "InstallRoot" and replaced it with a line for "sValueName" = "test". When I run this code under the debugger, I get a return value of null.

I've tried adding keys under SOFTWARE and values in that key like SOFTWARE\Testkey and I get the same result every time. It will not let me read a key I create, it always returns null, but it seems like I can read any key that already existed. I don't understand why I'm getting this result.

An FYI, is that I am doing a remote registry read from a Windows 7 PC. My ultimate goal is to be able to add registry keys and values. I've tried to do that and I always get an error exception "Not Found" when I try that, so I'm trying to get down to the easiest thing possible, which is to read a key and even that's not working. Any ideas for what might be going on here?

This is how I'm making the remote connection to the Windows 2008r2 server to read the registry:

```
              ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
              connectoptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
              connectoptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
              connectoptions.Username = "administrator";
              connectoptions.Password = **password redacted**

              ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + systemIP + @"\root\default");
              scope.Options = connectoptions;

              ManagementClass registry = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"), null);
```